# Error: target not found: xcb-util-wm

Tags: arch-linux, iso

So, I tried to create a custom Arch iso with `archiso` on Endeavour OS. I got this error - `error: target not found: xcb-util-wm`. How do I solve this issue???

Answer (score 1):

`xcb-util-wm` just cannot be found in the repositories your system is using, first update your packages `sudo pacman -Syy` then install it

```
sudo pacman -S xcb-util-wm
```